# Limit of Product of iid Random Variables

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, products

Let $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with common density function:
$f(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}I(x\geq 1)$ where $I(x\geq 1)$ is the indicator function and $\alpha >0$.  Now define:
$$S_n=\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i \right ]^{n^{-1}}$$
Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=e^{\alpha^{-1}}$, and use the law of large numbers and the continuous mapping theorem to conclude about the convergence in probability of $\ln(S_n)$.

I honestly don't have the slightest inkling on how to go about evaluating that limit.  However, since the value is given in the problem statment, my intuition tells me that $\ln(S_n)$ converges in probability to $\alpha^{-1}$, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is actually more like a hint, because:
$$\ln(S_n) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(X_k)$$
Now we find the density of $Y_k:=\ln(X_k) $. Let $y>0$,
$$P(Y_k<y) =P(\ln(X_k) <y)=P(X_k<e^y)$$
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus yields: $$f_Y(y) =e^y \frac{\alpha} {e^{(\alpha+1)y} }=\alpha e^{-\alpha y} $$
Hence $Y$ is exponentially distributed. Now by the SLLN we have 
$$\ln(S_n) \to E[Y_1]=\frac{1}{\alpha}\ \ \ \ \text{ a. s.} $$
And a. s. convergence implies convergence in probability. Moreover by the continuous mapping theorem we have...?

Can you finish?

Comment: Yeah, I can finish from here since we know the limit of $S_n$, but my issue was figuring out how to prove that given value using calculus in the first place.

Comment: So you actually wanted to do the exercise with the given order? I honestly don't know how to do that.

Comment: That's what I assumed I was supposed to do!  But who knows.